# AFNetworking and NSDictionary JSON by Index

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary, afnetworking

How can I get the JSON entries by index number with `NSDictionary`?

---

JSON Response:

```
{
    "data": {
        "first": [{
            "07:30": "Entry 1"
        }, {
            "09:05": "Entry 2"
        }, {
            "10:40": "Entry 3"
        }],
    },
    "success": true
}
```

Xcode (AFnetworking):

```
 [manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

      NSMutableArray *myArray = [responseObject objectForKey:@"data"];
      // OK, as NSDictionary have objectForKey.

      NSLog (@"%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:1] );
      // Error ;(
 }];
```

Comment: So, what is your problem?  You apparently didn't get an error, since you most certainly would have quoted that in your question if you did.

Comment: @HotLicks `NSDictionary` do not have `objectAtIndex`. But I`m not able to parse to a `NSArray`.

Comment: Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  Then understand that a JSON "object" maps to an NSDictionary and a JSON "array" maps to an NSArray.  You can't force one to be the other by simply naming the variable, you have to peel it like an onion, a layer at a time.

Comment: AND PUT YOUR ERROR MESSAGES (exact copy/paste) INTO YOUR QUESTION!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
[manager GET:url parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

      NSArray *myArray = [[responseObject objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"first"];

      NSLog (@"%@", [myArray objectAtIndex:1] ); 

 }];
```

You have something like below

```
{                  //<---- Dictionary
    "data": {      //<---- Dictionary
        "first": [ //<---- Array
        {          //<---- Dictionary
            "07:30": "Entry 1"
        }, {
            "09:05": "Entry 2"
        }, {
            "10:40": "Entry 3"
        }],
    },
    "success": true
}
```

Comment: I cannot use `objectAtIndex` with `NSDictionary`. Im trying to parse it to a `NSArray` but without success.

Comment: @LucianoNascimento You have dictionary of dictionary of array containing dictionary. `[myArray objectAtIndex:1]` will print dictionary. You can get value from dictionary using key from array object.